# Problem in performing translation of list of numbers to words such as [1,2,3] to [one,two,three]

Tags: prolog

Hello everyone I am trying to translate numbers to list of words. My logic seems to be correct but there is something wrong with the output. I am using swi-prolog in my Mac.

So when I enter 
translate([1,2,3],X).
it gives false.

```
means(0,zero).
means(1,one).
means(2,two).
means(3,three).
means(4,four).
means(5,five).
means(6.six).
means(7,seven).
means(8,eight).
means(9,nine).

translate([],[]).
translate([Head|Tail],[Head1|Tail1]):-
   means(Head,Head1),
   translate(Tail,Tail1).
```

Expected:

```
?- translate([1,2,3],X).
X = [one,two,three].
```

But got:

```
?- translate([1,2,3],X).
false.
```

Comment: You have a typo on the line `means(6.six).` a dot instead of a comma. Could that be related? With that corrected, your code does work in SWI Prolog here: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/ifypLKpL.pl

Comment: Thanks @ TessellatinHeckler it's my bad

Comment: You should also consider just using `maplist/3`: `maplist(means, [1,2,3], X)` ist the same as your `translate/2`.

Comment: Whenever you encounter such a problem, **generalize your query**. Like `translate([X,Y,Z], Ts)` or even `translate(Xs, Ts)`

Comment: SWI Prolog would have given you at least a warning of non-contiguous facts since `means(6.six)` looks to SWI Prolog as a single-argument fact, while the others are 2 argument. Make sure you investigate all warnings. Warnings are often clues to errors and should not be ignored.